# Android xml parsing inner elements?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am new to android dev, and just want to know about xml parsing, so I already have my structure to get the xml, but on parsing it, I have this setup:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        Log.d("onLoginHelper", e.toString());

                        //create the temp map of the specific item
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, xmlparser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_VALUE, xmlparser.getValue(e, KEY_VALUE));
```

etc

however, my key_value does not contain a value, the xml looks like this:

```
<member>
<name>test</name>
<value>
<int>0</int>
</value>
</member>

 <member>
 <name>testmsg</name>
    <value>
    <string>Success</string>
    </value>
 </member>
```

the value code is another xml element, but it can differ, so how would I get the value of that element inside my for loop?
thanx

Answer (score 0):

have a look a this demo:

1. http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94
2. http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/

You can also use `XmlPullParser` class for parsing xml.

```
Its recommend to use `XmlPullParser`, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android.
```

Have a look: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Tutorial using XmlPullParser: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html

Comment: thanx for the reply, but I already have a structure that I want to use, withouth changing to much, I only want to know how can I loop over the inner elements inside the value tag in my code?